# HowTo: Select items from an GraphQL object collection without referencing index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

So, I currently access items from an object by passing in the index id (0 to x), for example:

```html
data.allPostses[i].id
```

to access a returned result set of:

```html
  query allPostsCommentsQuery {
    allPostses {
      id
      displaysrc
      caption
      likes
      comments {
        id
        posts {
          id
        }
        text
        user
      }
    }
  }
```

How would I pass in only an id value to return display, caption etc?

For example I want to do something like:

```html
const recrd = data.allPostses[keys].id = id
```